# What is the best way to learn HTML 5

Tags: html

I want to learn HTML 5 and I am wondering where can i find best resources for HTML 5. 
It would be great if you share link/resources with examples.
Please provide your suggestions.

Thank You.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Core-HTML5-Canvas-Animation-Development/dp/0132761610/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1359104575&sr=8-1&keywords=html5+canvas

Comment: The best way to learn something depends on your personal preferences and your previous knowledge in related areas. As such, there is no single best way to learn HTML5. This is a polling question and not a good fit for the Q&A format of SO.

Comment: This question should be posted on Yahoo! Answers. Please, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @Oswald is right. Also note that some information on w3schools.com which was suggested by some answers are inaccurate. So it may not be the best resource.

Comment: I am sorry for adding such an open ended question but I think this will help beginners like me to find the best resources under one link.

Comment: I'm sure it will. That's why I will ask a question about what to do when your cat is on heat. I don't care that it's inappropriate on SO, because I think it will help novice cat holder.

Comment: @Oswald It doesn't matter what question you believe is noble or not, as a matter of fact SO has specific aims provided in the FAQ. Questions not respecting the FAQ must be avoided.

Comment: The best way to learn something is to start doing it!

Comment: Are you already an experienced web developer and just want to get your knowledge up to date, or are you a beginner and want to know how to build a website? When you don't have any experience, googling "HTML tutorial" instead of "HTML5 tutorial" will yield more relevant results.

Comment: I have used HTML. I have exprience in asp.net and ExtJS. I want to learn what's new with HTML 5, What is the diffrence between HTML 4 and HTML 5. Tip and tricks with HTML 5. Basically any resource which will help be learn HTML quickly.

Comment: Before this ends in an endless discussion please read "[Are questions asking for tutorials allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139008/190341)" or start a thread on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I learned it by reading through MDN and W3Schools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML and http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Answer (score 3):

To begin, I recommend you to try the Code School's HTML5 & CSS3 course.
Each course contains a video and pastebin-like exercices.
Not free, but cheap and very useful!

Their website : http://www.codeschool.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something basic why dont you try w3schools everything is there. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp.

or else you can see some code examples and learn them by playing with the codes
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/